# Wordpress Get Posts with parts by category

Tags: wordpress

I want to get posts on my header. 
Parts parts by the category, like this.

```
A Category
Post1
Post2
Post3
B Category
Post1
Post2
Post3
```

I don't want to use a lot of custom sql query.

Can i do that only one query?

Comment: jQuery? i write query

Answer (score 0):

That should do the trick:

```
<?php
add_filter('posts_join', create_function('$a', 'global $wpdb; return $a . " INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id) INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id) ";'));
add_filter('posts_where', create_function('$a', 'global $wpdb; return $a . " AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = \'category\'";'));
add_filter('posts_orderby', create_function('$a','global $wpdb; return "$wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id DESC";'));
query_posts($wp_query->query_vars);
?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ?>
```

Comment: You're awesome, thank you. But my confused :D how can i use this? Can you explain to me?

Comment: Just put the filters before the normal loop of posts. IF it doesn't work, put it in your theme's function.php.